# Is it possible to track custom ecommerce event in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

So can GA4 track non recommended ecommerce events?

For example if an event name is not in the list of [recommended events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en), can you still track it with ecommerce data like value, price, items etc?

I am tracking an event named "quick_order" and sending ecommerce data with the event to GA4, but in the DebugView, I am not able to see item level data with the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for now and not sure there is road map about it.

Usually will advice try to fit the behavior as EC events.

Take real estate website for example.

We might think browsing the house is view_item.

Another behavior on that website is add_to_cart

Submit the form is the purchase.

Then they can use EC report to analyze these behaviors.

Not sure it is the best solution but open to more creative feedbacks.